# Getting full path to an updated properties

Tags: gun

**Node.js to Node.js**, no browser, gun 0.8.7

Is there a way to be notified about a full path to an updated property in `gun`?

For, example, my listener

```
gun.get('task/123').map().on(function (t) {
  console.log(t);
});
```

fires the following update

```
{ _:
   { '#': 'j8pwhxy6Z121xeEvWjJk',
     '>': { num: 1507901726322, force: 1507901726322 } },
  num: 104,
  force: 23 }
```

Both of these properties are 2nd level properties behind `stat` property

```
{
  stat: {
    num: 104,
    force: 23
  }
}
```

I want to know what property these properties behind and a name of the node, for example `task/123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setupMap() {
  var path='task/123';
  gun.get(path).map().on(function (val,field) {
    console.log( path, field,'=',val );
   });
}
```

-or- This will return more direct values....

```
function setupMap() {
  var path='task/123';
  gun.get(path).map().map().on(function (val,field) {
    console.log( path, field,'=',val );
   });
}
```

-or-

```
function setupMap() {
  var path='task/123';
  gun.get(path).map().on(function (val,field) {
    console.log( this.back(-1)._['#'], field,'=',val );
   });
}
```

Comment: would `gun.get('tasks').map().get('stat').on(cb)` be more appropriate?

Comment: The question was more about getting the full path, so while that works, the value/field in cb is lacking that it came from tasks/X/stat/(stat_field).